# How to create a Numbering marker in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried to write CSS code style to produce the numbering marker that look like this

[image: Outcome of numbering marker]

But it does not look correctly the right shape of the trailing circle.

Here I've tried with CSS code:

```css
.comment-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2.45px solid #e7ad56;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.comment-icon:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  border-top: 2.45px solid #e7ad56;
  top: 20px;
  left: -6px;
  transform: rotate(286deg);
}

.comment-icon:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2.45px solid #e7ad56;
  top: 16px;
  left: -13px;
  transform: rotate(325deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-icon">1</div>
```

I have tried adjust `:before` and `:after` border positioning but did not get the right point at all.

Could anybody help get this shape please? Thanks.

Comment: Use an image as a background would be the simplest method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:before` and `:after` selectors to create an arrow and adjust the position on it.

```css
.comment-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2.45px solid #e7ad56;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.comment-icon:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ""; 
  top: 24px;
  left: -9px;  
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;  
  border-top: 15px solid #e7ad56;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.comment-icon:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ""; 
  top: 24px;
  left: -5px;  
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;  
  border-top: 12px solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-icon">1</div>
```

Comment: That's look really fine, thank you very much for help :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `SVG` with an arc in the path, as a background image and a flexible size

The benefit of this approach is

- a consistent visual rendering if you zoom the page;
- an *auto-fit* behaviour if the number starts to grow.

```css
.number {
   box-sizing: border-box;

   display: inline-grid;
   place-content: center;
   margin: .25rem;

   /* flexible width with logical properties */
   inline-size: max-content;
   min-inline-size: 2.8rem;
   padding: 0 .75rem;

   /* keeps the aspect ratio */
   aspect-ratio: 1;
   
   color: #444;
   font-family: system-ui, Arial;
   
   /* SVG background */
   background-image:
      url('data:image/svg+xml;UTF-8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -3 51 53"><path d="M4 35 A24 24 0 1 1 12 43L1 47z" fill="none" stroke="gold" stroke-width="3" /></svg>');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}

.number * {
   font-weight: normal; 
}


@supports (not (aspect-ratio: 1)) {
   /* if aspect-ratio is not supported then use 
    * padding-bottom in a ::before pseudoelement
    */
   .number *::before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-bottom: calc(100% + 1.5rem);
   }
}
```

```html
<span class="number"><b>1</b></span>
<span class="number"><b>82</b></span>
<span class="number"><b>239</b></span>
<span class="number"><b>69.420</b></span>
<span class="number"><b>4.060.752</b></span>
```

---

and here is the code of the SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -3 51 53">
   <path d="M4 35 A24 24 0 1 1 12 43L1 47z" 
         fill="none" stroke="gold" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

**Note**: as you may have noticed, the tickness of the stroke increases when the number inside the marker is really long.

If you want to *always* keep the same tickness just add `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` in the `SVG`, like in the following example

```css
.number {
   box-sizing: border-box;

   display: inline-grid;
   place-content: center;
   margin: .25rem;

   /* flexible width with logical properties */
   inline-size: max-content;
   min-inline-size: 2.8rem;
   padding: 0 .75rem;

   /* keeps the aspect ratio */
   aspect-ratio: 1;
   
   color: #444;
   font-family: system-ui, Arial;
   
   /* SVG background */
   background-image:
      url('data:image/svg+xml;UTF-8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -3 51 53"><path d="M4 35 A24 24 0 1 1 12 43L1 47z" fill="none" stroke="gold" stroke-width="3" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" /></svg>');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}

.number * {
   font-weight: normal; 
}


@supports (not (aspect-ratio: 1)) {
   /* if aspect-ratio is not supported then use 
    * padding-bottom in a ::before pseudoelement
    */
   .number *::before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-bottom: calc(100% + 1.5rem);
   }
}
```

```html
<span class="number"><b>1</b></span>
<span class="number"><b>82</b></span>
<span class="number"><b>239</b></span>
<span class="number"><b>69.420</b></span>
<span class="number"><b>4.060.752</b></span>
```

Tested on latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Here's how it looks with a `500%` zoom

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, this helps a lot. Anyway when using, which part I can adjust width of it ? Thanks so much :)

Comment: The width is ruled by min-inline-size. Just change that property.